# pyautogui の動作が止まるため改善したい

Tags: python, python3, pyautogui

pyautoguiにてタスクバーに入れているアプリを起動したいのですが、failsafeが働いて処理が止まってしまいます。
動作環境、コードは下記なのですが止めない方法はありますでしょうか。

▼環境
・自分のPC
・サーバーA
・サーバーB
※すべてリモートデスクトップ接続

▼処理内容
自身のPCからサーバーAに接続、サーバーAからサーバーBへ接続　させている状態
pyautoguiはサーバーBにて起動させています

上記だとうまく動作するのですが、自身のPCとサーバーAの接続を切ると動作が止まってしまうようです
サーバーAはサーバーBを開いている状態になっています

▼コード

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey("win", "5")
```

処理自体はこの後も続きますが、止まるのは頭のこの部分からになります
（5番目にはメモ帳が入っている状態）

▼エラー内容

```
pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED.
```

▼上のエラーを考慮してfailsafeをfalseにした場合

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False

pyautogui.hotkey("win", "5")
```

この場合はエラーこそでないのですが、そもそも処理がされていない状態になります
こちら問題なく動かすための方法などありますでしょうか

Comment: 重複候補: [クラウド上のWindows10でリモート接続していない状態でもpyautoguiを実行したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82592)

Comment: 上でいただいた重複候補にあった
Windowsイメージを2つ立ち上げ、pyautoguiを実行するマシンにもう一方からログインし続ける

を実行した形がこちらになります
（サーバーはスリープモードに入らないように設定されています）

Comment: 私も詳しいわけでは無いので詳しい回答は出来ませんが、「自分のPC から サーバーB」に直接接続でないのは何か理由がありますか？

Comment: 結局重複候補記事と同じでリモートデスクトップ接続が使われていて、それが切断されるからその現象が発生しているのでは？ 切断が起きないようにするか、リモートデスクトップ接続では無い方法で接続するくらいしか方法は無さそうです。あるいは、サーバーBに接続しているサーバーAのアカウントとPCから接続しようとしているサーバーAのアカウントが同じか否かで変わるのかもしれませんが。直接は関係無いですが、こんな記事から何かひらめくかもしれません。[WindowsPC1台で「2アカウント同時ログイン」してデスクトップを2つ使う【RDP】](https://qiita.com/jakenjarvis@github/items/8b6108f0f30e7e9fae6b)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
一度別の方法で接続するのを試してみるようにします。